# MISRA C++ 2008 strange warning

Tags: c++

Here is the code below,

```
std::stringstream os;
for (size_t i = 0U; i < len; i++) {
    os << static_cast<uint32_t>(src[i]);
}
```

> Warning is: "advisory Rule 14-8-2, Viable set contains both function
>   and template: std::basic_ostream::operator<<"

for the below line of code

```
os << static_cast<uint32_t>(src[i]);
```

Please suggest how to resolve the same, i am new to c++ and sure sure about the same.

Comment: There's no more information in the message? Please edit your question to include the complete message.

Comment: @Joachim The complete message *is* included right below the first code snippet. This is one of those silly Misra rules that is being triggered because [`basic_ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) defines a member `operator<<` which is a set of non-template overloads, and also a set of free function template versions. As the warning says, the candidate set for overload resolution includes both of these - function templates and non-templates.

Comment: … which is only of many reasons not to use the Misra C++ coding standards. It has a rather Misrable set of rules.

Answer (score 3):

The Misra warning is being triggered because [`basic_ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) defines a member [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) which is a set of non-template overloads, and also a set of [free function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) versions. As the warning says, the candidate set for overload resolution includes both of these - function templates and non-templates.

Your options are to either suppress the warning for this line, or figure out a way to not use `operator<<` to perform formatted output. The latter can be done by creating an intermediate string representation of the number, and then using [`basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to output the characters. If you have a C++11 compiler, you can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to do this.

```
auto s = std::to_string(42U);
std::stringstream ss;

ss.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
```

If you can't use `to_string`, or need additional formatting, there's always `s(n)printf` for creating the string representation.

My personal opinion is to suppress that warning, with the justification being that you're using a well defined and well known type from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very general type: std::stringstream. Possible is

```
template<class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<< (basic_ostream<charT,traits>&& os, const T& val);
```

and also

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Herb Sutter has a great article about why this rule makes sense. It has to do with the specific order in which the C++ standard handles overloading resolution between template and non-template functions. The actual function chosen may not always follow the expectation of the programmer. Here is the link:
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Seems the STL has some mildly dangerous code in there.